# How to validate input parameters in C++ constructor?

Tags: c++, validation, c++11, constructor

Following example shows the crux of the problem. I need to initialize const members of a class. This can only be done in the initializer-list and not in constructor body. I want to assert or throw an error if input to the constructor is invalid, that is, if the vector size is less than 3.

```
class A {
 // In following constructor, how do we make sure if params.size()
 // is at least 3.
 A(const std::vector<int>& params):
  x(params[0]), y(params[1]), z(params[2]) {}
private:
  const int x;
  const int y;
  const int z;
};
```

Please advise how to achieve this in Modern C++ (11 and later)

Comment: Use std::at() instead of operator[].

Comment: Beware that `const` data members come with restrictions. You won't be able to assign to `A`. Often, invariant members are kept constant by virtue of the type's interface offering no means of changing them other than assigning an entire new `A` value to the object.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a pretty good use-case for [contracts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/contract), should you have a c++20 compliant compiler at hand.

Comment: Do I read this correctly? Violating this constraint is a programming error. Why use std::vector instead of 3 arguments?

Comment: Trivial point. Did you mean to write `z(params[2])`?

Comment: @TimRandall Yes my bad. That was a typo. Edited the question.

Comment: @JVApen, Agreed in this particular case, using std::vector does not make much sense. So, please don't read too much into the example. Example is just there to illustrate the actual question about how to validate constructor arguments before they are used in an initializer-list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add a layer of abstraction.  You can write a function that makes sure the vector is of the correct size and you can even make sure the values are in an expected range, if you have one.  That would look like

```
class A {
 A(const std::vector<int>& params):
  x(verify(params, 0)), y(verify(params, 1)), z(verify(params, 3)) {}
private:
  static int verify(const std::vector<int>& params, int index) 
  { 
    if (params.size() < 4) // or use if (params.size() <= index) if you only care if the index will work
      throw something; 
    return params[index]; 
  }
  const int x;
  const int y;
  const int z;
};
```

Comment: `size() <= index` would make more sense than `size() != 4`

Comment: @RemyLebeau The OP specificly called out to error if the size was less than 4.  I suppose I should use `params.size() < 4` to satisfy that.

Comment: The OP said "*if the vector size is inferior to 4*" as well as "*if params.size()
is at least 3*", so that is kind of contradictory. Personally, I think the 4 is a typo, and index 3 should be 2 instead. It doesn't make much sense to pass in a 4-element vector where there is a gap between the `xy` and `z` values. A 3-element vector makes more sense.  But either way, `size() <= index` still makes more sense in your `verify()` function, since it is performing bounds checking to make sure the provided `index` is valid

Comment: @RemyLebeau Very true.  At least now it should show them with whatever way they want to do it.

Comment: I thought of this as a solution. But, it felt like a hack. Looks like C++ does not have a more specific way to validate constructor arguments. We can do something like following to make it less verbose.
x(verify(params) ? params[0] : assert(0)), y(params[1]), z(params[2])

Comment: @PunitSoni You could do that.  I just used `verify` on all 3 parameters in case you wanted to do bounds checking.  If you only care about the size then you could call `verify` just in the `x` initialization.

Comment: @PunitSoni why does it need a specific way?

Answer (score 7):

`const` members can only be initialized in the constructors's member initialization list.  To validate the caller's input, you would have to call a helper function to validate each input value before passing it to the corresponding member, eg:

```
int check(const std::vector<int> &params, int index) {
  if (params.size() <= index) throw std::length_error("");
  return params[index];
}

class A {
 A(const std::vector<int>& params):
  x(check(params, 0)), y(check(params, 1)), z(check(params, 3)) {}
private:
  const int x;
  const int y;
  const int z;
};
```

Or, simply utilize the [`vector`'s own built-in bounds checking](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) instead:

```
class A {
 A(const std::vector<int>& params):
  x(params.at(0)), y(params.at(1)), z(params.at(3)) {}
private:
  const int x;
  const int y;
  const int z;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Not as elegant as other solutions but... you can simply add a `throw` in a ternary operator inside the initialization of the first constant

```
class A
 {
   private:
      const int x;
      const int y;
      const int z;

   public:    
      A (const std::vector<int>& params)
         : x{ params.size() < 4u ? throw std::runtime_error{"!"}
                                 : params[0] },
           y{params[1]}, z{params[3]}
      { }
 };
```

Off Topic suggestion: if `A` is a `class`, maybe it's better that the constructor is `public`.

Answer (score 0):

Other option extra layer through conversion:

```
class A_params{
   friend class A;
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;
   void validate();
   public:
   A_params(std::initializer_list<int>);
   A_params(const std::vector<int>&);
   A_params(int(&)[3]);
   //...
   };


class A {
 // In following constructor, how do we make sure if params.size()
 // is at least 3.
public:
 A(A_params params):
  x(params.x), y(params.y), z(params.z) {}
private:
  const int x;
  const int y;
  const int z;
};
```

Comment: This just moves the problem of validation to `A_params`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Validation is not the problem! The problem is executing a peace of code before member-list initialization. C'est difficile l'anglais non?

Comment: You will have the same problem in implementing `A_params::A_params(const std::vector<int>&)`. That's what I mean by moving the problem to `A_params`. Oui, l'anglais est parfois difficile : peace = paix et piece = morceau.

Comment: I guess I missed the point. The point of using member initialization was because 'A''s members are `const`, and if that's the only reason than this answer will work since `A_params` doesn't need `const` members.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with `operator,`: in a list of instructions separated by `,` only the last one is used as value. You have to encapsulate it between braces. Example with assert:

```
A(const std::vector<int>& params):
  x((assert(params.size() > 0), params[0])),
  y((assert(params.size() > 1), params[1])),
  z((assert(params.size() > 2), params[2]))
{ /*...*/ }
```